# Limiting Value of $f_n(x)$?

Tags: calculus

I have a query relating to finding the limiting function of the following sequence of functions. Apologize in advance if the problem is too basic.

If $f_n(x) = 2 n x ~;~ x \in \big [0, \dfrac {1}{n} \big ]$, then how do we find the value of $$\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n(x)?$$

Original problem statement was : $f_n$ is the sequence of all real functions defined on $[0,1]$ by setting :

$ f_n(x) =   \begin{cases} 
             2nx & ;0 \le x \leq \dfrac {1}{n} \\
             \dfrac{2n(1-x)}{n-1} & ;\dfrac {1}{n} \leq x\leq 1 \\
             \end{cases}$

**Attempt:**

When $0 \le x \le \dfrac {1}{n}$

then : $ 0 \le x \le \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac {1}{n}$

$\implies $ When $n \rightarrow \infty, x \rightarrow 0$

Then, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n(x) = 2 \times \infty \times 0$ form which is indeterminate.

My textbook mentions this limit being equal to $0$ however.

Could someone please explain how to calculate this limit?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The functions $f_n$ do not have a common domain, so it doesn't make too much sense to talk about a limit function (the only point common to all domains is $0$)

Comment: I have included the original problem statement in my question. Could you please have a look again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix any $x \neq 0$. As long as $n$ is large enough, $x \notin [0,1/n]$, so that $f_n(x)=\frac{2n(1-x)}{n-1} \to 2(1-x)$ as $n \to +\infty$. If $x=0$, then $f_n(0)=0$.

Comment: I have included the original problem statement in my question. Could you please have a look again?

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much.